# Connecting to Snowflake with DataGrip fequent timeout errors

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datagrip

When working with Snowflake through DataGrip I often get the following timeout error:
JDBC driver encountered communication error. Message: Exception encountered for HTTP request: Operation timed out.

Usually on a second attempt it will be fine, but I always need to wait for this timeout to occur before I can do anything. If I continue to run queries after getting the initial connection it will be fine, but if I was to leave the application for a few minutes, again when I come back it struggles to re-connect for the next query.

My suspicion is that this occurs when the Snowflake warehouse is suspended. It seems like it is waiting on some acknowledgment that the warehouse has been resumed.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Is it happening after a connection was established or during the first attempt to establish a connection? Can you maybe post the entire line, is there anything else besides the error message you posted? There should probably some more information in the log.

Comment: Not much else in the log apart from this `SEVERE: Stop retrying since elapsed time due to network issues has reached timeout. Elapsed: 110,513(ms), timeout: 60,000(ms)` It happens on the first attempt

Comment: Ok, that does help. It's the [login timeout](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-parameters.html#logintimeout) which is by default 1 min. Do you have any proxy/firewall in your network?

Comment: No I'm on a home network.

Comment: If it's intermittent, then you probably have some network issues. That's where I would start looking at.